# C++ "vector of vectors"

Tags: c++, vector

I have to create a `std::vector` containing vectors of `Eigen::Vector2d`. This is how I do the declaration :

```
std::vector< std::vector< Eigen::Vector2d > >  markingsPointSets;
```

and I try to push back some elements I created like that :

```
Eigen::Vector2d firstMarkingPoint(markingPointA[0] + AB_perp[0] * .15, markingPointA[1] + AB_perp[1] * .15); // Don't mind to the value of this variable :p

markingsPointSets.at(i).push_back(firstMarkingPoint);
```

but this gives me :

```
error c2719 formal parameter with __declspec(align('16')) won't be aligned
```

Please tell me if there are some missing information to find the source of this problem.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Just a wild guess, but is `Vector2d` declared with specific alignment settings that might not be guaranteed when putting it into a `std::vector`?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25300116/directxxmmatrix-error-c2719-declspecalign16-wont-be-aligned).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have not read the [documentation](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TopicStlContainers.html):

> Using STL containers on fixed-size vectorizable Eigen types, or classes having members of such types, requires taking the following two steps:
>
> - A 16-byte-aligned allocator must be used. Eigen does provide one ready for use: aligned_allocator.
> - **If you want to use the `std::vector` container, you need to #include < Eigen/StdVector >.**
>
> These issues arise only with fixed-size vectorizable Eigen types and structures having such Eigen objects as member. For other Eigen types, such as Vector3f or MatrixXd, no special care is needed when using STL containers.

(emphasis mine)